# How to multiply DM and DV of DiffSharp in C#?

Tags: c#, diffsharp

I have the following code:

```
    using DiffSharp.Interop.Float64;

public class Layer
{
       public DM W { get; set; }
       public DV b { get; set; }
       public Func<DV,DV> a { get; set; }

       public DV Compute(DV v)
       {
          return a(W * v); // This Line
       }
}
```

The problem is i the statement `W * v` and it says `"Operator * cannot be applied to operands of type DM and DV"`. In F# they are multiplied in this manner. How can we multiply this matrix and vector in C#?

Comment: Not sure how vector is done in f#,but in c#,you need to load System.Windows.Vector assembly-you can check :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms599648(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Take a look at the source code: https://github.com/DiffSharp/DiffSharp/blob/master/src/DiffSharp/Interop.Float64.fs  Notice that it defines a lot of mulitplication operators, but none of them are `DM * DV`. Perhaps the authors of the library accidentally omitted the operator you want from the interop library?

Comment: `DM` and `DV` are 2 different types. Your `Compute` method either need to do something special or call special method of `DV` (to do something with `DM` type inside disregards what is it doing).

Comment: @EricLippert You are absolutely right. DV * DV exists. DM * DM exists but DM * DV doesn't. Thank you very much. I guess I should open an issue?